# How to get latest Snapshot for a volume in AWS using API

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want only the latest snapshot for a specific volume.

```
response_v=boto3.client("ec2").describe_snapshots(Filters=[{"Name":"volume-id","Values":["vol-fffffffffff"]}])
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `describe_snapshots` method returns the newest one first but you really shouldn't count on that.

I think you can safely rely on the `StartTime` field, looking for the greatest value for all snapshots returned.

> Snapshots occur asynchronously; the point-in-time snapshot is created immediately

Because of that the "largest" StartTime will be the latest snapshot

I wrote this bit of code to print the snapshot_id with the latest snapshot start time.  My python-fu is not the greatest but this works.

```
import boto3
import datetime
import pytz

utc = pytz.UTC
starttime=datetime.datetime(1,1,1,tzinfo=utc)
snap_id = ""
volume_id = "<put your volume id here or write something more elegant to pass it in>"

region = 'us-east-1'
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')

ec2 = session.client('ec2', region_name=region)

response = ec2.describe_snapshots(Filters=[{"Name":"volume-id","Values":[volume_id]}])

# print(response['Snapshots'])
for snap in response['Snapshots']:
    if snap['StartTime'] > starttime:
        snap_id = snap['SnapshotId']
        starttime= snap['StartTime']

print(snap_id)
```

#### References

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html